# oracle verify insert then delete dynamic tables

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sql-insert, sql-delete

Is there any way i can verify if my inserts were successful into my secondary table and then deleting from my original table those rows, without using a trigger.

SO i have this query: has 2 dynamic tables n_tab and n_tab2

```
testes:= 'INSERT all into ' || n_tab2 || ' SELECT * FROM ' || n_tab || ' where criado_em< ' || SYSDATE;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE testes;
```

after this insert i would like to verify if all the rows were inserted and after that

```
stmt_del:= 'DELETE FROM ' || n_tab || ' WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
 FROM ' || n_tab2 || ' WHERE '  'need to find a way to associate the pk and fk dinamically'
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE testes;
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: hint : try `returning into` clause.

Comment: to use returning i would need to delete and then insert? I've never used it before

Comment: Why not use SQL%ROWCOUNT SQL attribute to count the rows?

Comment: i can understand barbados idea, if i knew all the columns that i would be using, but i dont , so i dont think that would work.

Ankit do you know any examples i can take a look at?

Comment: `criado_em<'|| SYSDATE` is very bad. Use `criado_em < :d'; EXECUTE IMMEDIATE testes USING SYSDATE;`

Comment: What do you mean by "like to verify if all the rows were inserted"? If the insert fails for whatever reason then you will get an exception.

Answer (score 0):

if not find any way , here is way using SQL%ROWCOUNT

```
DECLARE

stmt varchar2(100);
mycolumn NUMBER := 100 ;

BEGIN

stmt := 'insert into mytable values('||mycolumn||')';
execute immediate stmt;
dbms_output.put_line('value '||SQL%ROWCOUNT);

IF SQL%ROWCOUNT > 1 THEN

stmt_del:= 'delete from mytable where condition';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE testes;
END IF;

END;
```

Comment: sorry , i dont see how that can help me in my case.

Comment: I see once insert got success you need to delete ... this SQL%ROWCOUNT will give values based on number of inserts...then what is expected I didn't

Comment: so i could delete to the row count, and in case i dont throw an exception and do a rollback? to a savepoint ? , i want to insert the data and delete, but i dont want to end up losing it in case the insert fails

Comment: I didn't get exactlywhat you want to do ... you can test with different scenarios but to verify whether its inserted or not its one way

Comment: created a new question trying to explain better what i pretend

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53156179/oracle-insert-into-table2-then-delete-from-table1-exception-if-fail